# Delombok can't find symbol for all dependencies

Tags: java, lombok

I am trying to delombok a project using the command:

```
java -jar lombok-1.18.8.jar delombok C:\Users\halaeddine\IdeaProjects\projectName -d "D:\OneDrive - Haydar\Desktop\delomboked"  --classpath=C:\Users\halaeddine\.gradle\*
```

the gradle folder contains all jar dependendencies.
I am getting the following errors:

```
error: package X does not exist
```

for each external library used in the code

Answer (score 1):

Delombok replicates the `javac` options which means that after `--classpath` you need to specify all of the jars or directories containing class files. The gradle directory will likely contain subdirectories containing jar files and `javac` doesn't recurse into these, nor will your shell expand into them. Your best option is to use `gradle` to build up the list of relevant jars. Alternatively you could write a shell script to find them all and put the locations into a colon or semicolon separated list.

Comment: Finding them all may unfortunately find many versions of a library, thus resulting in things like `NoSuchMethodError`. This is IMHO too dangerous - you really need to get the libraries exactly like specified in `build.gradle`.